# Puppet crontab entry not created

Tags: puppet

I am trying to add a cron entry using puppet.  I have this code in my class:

```
cron { 'puppet-apply':
    ensure  => present,
    command => "/usr/bin/mycommand",
    user    => root,
    hour    => '14',
    minute  => '49',
    require => File['mycommand'],
}
```

`mycommand` is another definition in the same class. When puppet runs, `mycommand` executable is correctly added to `/usr/bin`, however I do not see any crontab entries created in `/etc/crontab` (or anywhere else for that matter).

What am I missing here? How can I get it to create the crontab entry?

Comment: Are you checking the crontab with the same user that is applying puppet?

Comment: @MattSchuchard I'm applying puppet as root. I checked all cron-related files in /etc as well as /root directory

Comment: Have you actually checked root's crontab?  That would be `crontab -l`, or probably `/var/spool/cron/root`.

Comment: @larsks yes, I did. `crontab -l` results in _no crontab for root_

Comment: It's a good question by the way, not sure why it is downvoted so many times and what all the close votes are about.

Comment: @AleksG, I didn't see your comments here. If crontab -l results in no crontab for root then apparently something else is wrong too. It would be best to firstly try the test I have shown to understand further at what point things break.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine, and I suspect you are just misunderstanding how Puppet manages cron tabs.

If you are using the latest Puppet, the source code for the cron logic is [here](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-cron_core). Notice the actual files used by OS type [here](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-cron_core/blob/master/lib/puppet/provider/cron/crontab.rb#L265-L274):

```ruby
CRONTAB_DIR = case Facter.value('osfamily')
              when 'Debian', 'HP-UX', 'Solaris'
                '/var/spool/cron/crontabs'
              when %r{BSD}
                '/var/cron/tabs'
              when 'Darwin'
                '/usr/lib/cron/tabs/'
              else
                '/var/spool/cron'
              end
```

So given code like this:

```puppet
file { 'mycommand':
  path    => "/usr/bin/mycommand",
  content => "#!/usr/bin/bash\necho hello world",
}

cron { 'puppet-apply':
  ensure  => present,
  command => "/usr/bin/mycommand",
  user    => root,
  hour    => '14',
  minute  => '49',
  require => File['mycommand'],
}
```

If you apply that as root on CentOS 7:

```
[root@centos-72-x64 ~]# puppet apply /tmp/apply_manifest.pp
Notice: Compiled catalog for centos-72-x64.macquarie.local in environment production in 0.05 seconds
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/File[mycommand]/ensure: defined content as '{md5}8d9f82443e4fb78b8316c17174182d16'
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/Cron[puppet-apply]/ensure: created
Notice: Applied catalog in 0.04 seconds
```

You will have the expected crontab:

```
[root@centos-72-x64 ~]# crontab -l 
# HEADER: This file was autogenerated at 2019-11-09 03:55:09 +0000 by puppet.
# HEADER: While it can still be managed manually, it is definitely not recommended.
# HEADER: Note particularly that the comments starting with 'Puppet Name' should
# HEADER: not be deleted, as doing so could cause duplicate cron jobs.
# Puppet Name: puppet-apply
49 14 * * * /usr/bin/mycommand
```

And the actual files modified are in `/var/spool/cron`:

```
[root@centos-72-x64 ~]# find /var/spool/cron
/var/spool/cron
/var/spool/cron/root
[root@centos-72-x64 ~]# cat /var/spool/cron/root
# HEADER: This file was autogenerated at 2019-11-09 03:55:09 +0000 by puppet.
# HEADER: While it can still be managed manually, it is definitely not recommended.
# HEADER: Note particularly that the comments starting with 'Puppet Name' should
# HEADER: not be deleted, as doing so could cause duplicate cron jobs.
# Puppet Name: puppet-apply
49 14 * * * /usr/bin/mycommand
```